# How do I write an IF statement in excel that returns a mix of formulas and text?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am attempting to achieve the following through a single formula to simplify my excel sheet:

[image: Excel Screen Shot]

If "Gross INV-Bill Difference" is 0, then "MI"

If "Gross INV-Bill Difference" is <0 then "UI([Gross INV-Bill Difference] Gross/ [Net INV-Bill Difference] Net)"

If "Gross INV-Bill Difference" is >0 then "OI([Gross INV-Bill Difference] Gross/[Net INV-Bill Difference] Net)"

So far i only have

`=IF(I14=0,"MI", "Not MI")`

Comment: Can you post your attempted code so far, then? And explain why it doesn't suffice.

Comment: Is this an actual table (formatted as such with Ctrl+T)? Note - all you need to do is just concatenate the text portions (UI, Gross/, Net) with `&`.

Comment: so far i only have `=IF(I14=0,"MI", "Not MI") ` I am unsure how to acheive the other outcomes should I14 be positive or negative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming A1 start use:

```
=IF(A2-B2=0,"MI",IF(A2-B2<0,"UI("&TEXT(A2,"$#,##0.00;-$#,##0.00;;")&" Gross/"&TEXT(B2,"$#,##0.00;-$#,##0.00;;")&" Net)","OI("&TEXT(A2,"$#,##0.00;-$#,##0.00;;")&" Gross/"&TEXT(B2,"$#,##0.00;-$#,##0.00;;")&" Net)"))
```